# Fetching data from Secured website(https) through power query

Tags: powerquery

I seek your guidance for fetching data from secured website which starts with https through power query. When I paste link in from web option in power query, it does not pull any data and gives only one row of null data. Is there any way that I can fetch data through power query? I do have a login credentials for my login and it works well in web browser but not in power query.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to use login credentials for websites, depending on how the credential should be applied.

If the website accepts Basic auth, you can enter a username and password.

On the other hand, if the website uses something custom like storing cookies in your browser, that won't work today in Power Query.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance Carl. How do I know that website accepts coockies or not?

Comment: You can always try to input your password and see if it works. If that doesn't work, it's a bit technical, but you can see how the browser auhenticates using the great tool [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).